# How to insert correctly different pictures to a single file 

Tags: python, linux, image, image-processing, gimp

I don't know if it's possible, since my knowledge of image processing is low. I need to put my passport size photo on an A4 sheet so that I could print it out out. I tried using GIMP, great tool. Like I said earlier my expertise is very low in this field. I find it difficult to place the photos efficiently in A4 sheet.

Is there any way of placing it programmatically. Looking for some scripts using python... so that I could get a perfect output.

Or is there any program that makes this work easier. Or the last chance is to use GIMP more effectively?

Comment: Easiest way if this is a one-off, would e to create a tale in word and paste copies of the image into each cell.

Comment: If you know HTML and CSS then you can line the images up in an HTML file and print that. That can be automated too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use imagemagick:

```
$ convert -append photo1.jpg photo2.jpg photo3.jpg row1.jpg
```

Or try +append to change the orientation.

Repeat as needed:

```
$ convert +append row1.jpg row2.jpg row3.jpg a4.jpg
```

I may have gotten the -append and the +append mixed up.

Comment: If you need borders around each photo then you can add them to each photo using imagemagick too, before appending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use imagemagick
[Imagemaick command line tools](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php)

[Examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/)